# Using Hall's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am currently studying the Math for CS course on MIT OCW, I am stuck on the following question for which I cannot find a solution:

> Scholars through the ages have identified twenty fundamental human
>   virtues: honesty, generosity, loyalty, prudence, completing the weekly
>   course reading-response, etc. At the beginning of the term, every
>   student in 6.042 possessed exactly eight of these virtues.
>   Furthermore, every student was unique; that is, no two students
>   possessed exactly the same set of virtues. The 6.042 course staff must
>   select one additional virtue to impart to each student by the end of
>   the term. Prove that there is a way to select an additional virtue for
>   each student so that every student is unique at the end of the term as
>   well.
>
> Suggestion: Use Hall’s theorem. Try various interpretations for the
>   vertices on the left and right sides of your bipartite graph.

I have partitioned G in X and Y where X is the set of virtues with |X|=20 and Y is the student. I know that the cardinality of every vertex in X is 8, and that there is a unique matching, but I don't know how to progress.

Comment: Side note: Get rid of insignificant details, such as $6.042$. They are confusing as well as irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: There might be ${20\choose8}=125\,970$ students, each of them craving for one of ${20\choose9}=167\,960$ combinations of $9$ virtues, whereby each student is connected to only $12$ of these combinations. It won't be easy $\ldots$

Comment: Hint: in case it's not obvious, @ChristianBlatter's musing is really a hint: you might try a different $G$...

Comment: My first thought would be to define the vertex classes the possible combinations of 8 and combinations of 9 virtues, can anyone formalise this?

Answer (score 1):

We have to envisage the possibility that there are ${20\choose 8}=125\,970$ students, each of them incorporating another set of $8$ virtues. On the other hand there are ${20\choose 9}=167\,960$ combinations of $9$ virtues.

We therefore set up a bipartite graph $G$ with vertex set $L\cup R$ as follows: On the left we have  ${20\choose 8}$ vertices $v$ representing the collections of $8$ virtues, and on the right we have ${20\choose 9}$ vertices $w$ representing the collections of $9$ virtues. From each eight-set $v$ draw edges to the $12$ nine-sets $w$ containing $v$ as a subset.

I claim that this graph meets the condition of Hall's theorem.

*Proof.* Consider any nonempty subset $P\subset L$, and let $Q\subset R$ be the set of vertices connected to at least one $v\in P$. There are $12|P|$ edges emanating from $P$, but any $w\in Q$ can receive at most $9$ of them. It follows that
$$|Q|\geq{12|P|\over 9}>|P|\ .\qquad\square$$
Hall's theorem therefore guarantees the existence of a perfect matching. A practical procedure then could be as follows: Using a constructive proof of Hall's theorem the staff of course 6.042 sets up a lookup table for all correspondences $v\mapsto w$ once and for all. Any student signing in for the course would then have to name her eight virtues whereupon she will be assigned a ninth according to the table.